# How to select n character after regex match

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, regex-negation

I am having url `'http:abc.com/test/test1/123-343$fsdsf$gdgdgfdgfdg35435435'`

i want to select 36 characters occur after `'http:abc.com/test/test1/'`
i had wrote regex `(?<=http[s]?://abc.com/\w*/\w*/)` which match the pattern.
The problem is with selector.
i want to select next 36 char after pattern match.

i was trying  `(?<=http[s]?://abc.com/\w*/\w*/){36}`
but it is not working.

the big problem is after pattern match there can be less than 36 char present.
i want to handle this situation as well.
i.e If char present after pattern match are less than 36, then select what ever number of char present after pattern match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=https?:\/?\/?abc\.com\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/).{1,36}
```

You can try this.`{1,36}` will allow to capture character even if it less than `36`.